# Regular expression to get jade includes

Tags: javascript, regex, pug

Can you please give me any help to get jade includes with regular expression.

http://jade-lang.com/

My code looks like this

```
html
    body
        .container
           include header.jade
           include body part
           include footer part.jade
```

Regx should give

```
header.jade
body part
footer part.jade
```

I have tried this but it works for file names without spaces but fails with the file which contain spaces.

```
/include\s([^\n\s]+)*/g;
```

Comment: your question isn't understandable. Please explain us exactly that you want.

Comment: Just remove `\s` from character class.

Comment: Removing \s gives me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to match the include with a group for the rest of the line

```
/include\s+(.*)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

`/include\s{1}[\s\w0-9]+\.jade/;`

Comment: Nope the string after include can be anything.

Comment: Oh, i thought you need only the ones with the extension .jade.